# What else can I use to clean glass windows?

Tags: windows, cleaning

I have a job scheduled that involves getting a house ready to sell. The customer wants it cleaned and polished as she is putting it on the market. It's a 3 story 1950's era house that has a lot of glass windows and doors (a lot). The windows are original single-pane casement. Every one has mullions that divide the pane into single panes (about 12" x 12"). I have to clean every window. What is the fastest way to accomplish this? I've heard newspaper can be substituted for paper towels?

Comment: I used to clean my car windows with newspaper and it works well, but I'd be worried about the ink on the paint of the mullions.  Glass cleaning microfiber is a good option, or unprinted newsprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Black ink newspapers work but they are messy and difficult.

If you have a lot of glass to do, duplicate how the professionals do it. They use dishwashing liquid solution (not an ammonia based glass cleaner like *%$dex). They use a soft absorbent scrubber (you could use a soft sponge mop maybe?), then they use a good quality squeegee to remove the grimy liquid from the glass. Follow that up with a quick *dry* rag wipe of the edges and corners.

You might think about blasting all the windows with a water stream first, to remove as much loose dirt from the sashes and mullions as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Coffee filters work like newspaper without the ink.

http://www.bobvila.com/articles/quick-tip-clean-windows-with-coffee-filters/#.VmZa83Qo7qA

Answer (score 1):

I used those bottles of cleaner from HD that attach to your hose. It pre-soaks, cleans and rinses. I usually do that for the windows I can't reach  and I don't even have to wipe dry. Hardly any spots.

Answer (score 1):

It is good to use a squeegee to clean the window. It is easy and takes a short period of time to clean as clear as a crystal